# ios swift parsing authentication

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, swift

I'm trying to parse an XML Feed in Swift using NSXMLParser and some of it's functions (didStartElement, didEndElement, etc).

However, it returns nil because I have to authenticate (user name and password) every time I try to parse it.

How do I implement the authentication in my NSXMLParser functions?

Code:

```
let feedUrlString:String = "http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-treinplanner?fromStation=Zaltbommel&toStation=Rotterdam+Centraal"
var trainOptions:[TrainOption] = [TrainOption]()

// Parser variables
var currentElement:String = ""
var foundCharacters:String = ""
var attributes:[NSObject:AnyObject]?
var currentlyConstructingOption:TrainOption = TrainOption()

func getTrainRoute() {

    let feedUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: feedUrlString)
    let feedParser:NSXMLParser? = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: feedUrl!)

    if let actualFeedParser = feedParser {

        actualFeedParser.delegate = self
        actualFeedParser.parse()

    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    // TO DO

    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {

    // TO DO

    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {

    // TO DO

    }
}

func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser!) {

    // TO DO
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You have to authenticate for parsing, or you have to authenticate for be allowed to get the XML infos from the server through the WebService, which coule be what you really need. If that's the case it's up to your server to give you the step to be authenticated.

Comment: That last one. I have to authenticate to be allowed to get the XML info from the server through the web service.

Comment: Read the doc of your webservice.

Comment: You'll have to use another method of fetching the XML that allows for authentication.  `NSXMLParser(contentsOfUrl:)` doesn't allow for modification of the HTTP request (and by extension, authentication).  Take a look at `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`